# Trying to retrieve a JSONObject, why is my site 404ing?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, http-status-code-404

```
@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(Long... ids) {
    id=ids[0];

    apiURL="http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=534FA68616FC166C4A9F11CEB01B9929&steamid=76561197976528744&format=json";
    DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(apiURL);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();
        jObject=new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (Exception e) { 

    }
    finally {
        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception ex){}
    }
    return jsonArray;




}
```

In the above code, I have a break point on the sb.append() line. Watching this line, I can see that I'm getting a 404 error, however if you copy and paste the url in your browser you will see it's a valid address. I'm using the internet permission in my manifest so I'm not sure what's going on here. Any ideas as to why its 404ing?

Comment: Copying that URL into your browser does a `GET`. You're going a `POST`, and yes, that's exactly what attempting to POST to that URL returns.

Comment: Thank you, changed it to a get and all is well now. If you'd like to submit I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying that URL into your browser does a `GET`. You're going a `POST`.

Checking with `curl`, indeed a `404` is returned if you POST to that url:

> curl -XPOST "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=534FA68616FC166C4A9F11CEB01B9929&steamid=76561197976528744&format=json"

```
<html>
<head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
</body>
</html>
```